# How we can create VM ware using Azure data Factory

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-machine, azure-vm-role

**I am trying to create Vmware using VMImage through Azure data factory!**

I am able to create manually by using Resource Manager, but i want to automate this process through Azure Data Factory.

Comment: sorry, but what are you asking for? Data Factory is not meant to automate deployments

Answer (score 0):

If you can call a Azure Runbook from Azure Automation, then consider it done!
Also you can call the run book by a webjobs [Link] (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem like an appropriate use of Azure Data Factory (ADF) which is primarily an ELT tool.  Consider [Azure DevOps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/devops/), [Azure Arc](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/azure-arc/) or [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/) which would be more appropriate for an Infrastructure as Code approach.

Or maybe just a bit of Powershell!?